# django：When I click on the text1 page, the page does not jump to my article

Tags: python, django

When I click on text 1, the page does not respond
this is urls：

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'$',views.blog_title,name='blog_title'),
    url(r'(?P<article_id>\d)/$',views.blog_article,name='blog_article'),
]
```

this is views：

```
def blog_article(request,article_id):
  article = models.BlogArticle.objects.get(id = article_id)
  return render(request,'blog/article.html',{'article':article})
```

this is html：

```
<div>
   <a>{{ article.body }}</a>
</div>
```

this is  html:

```
<div>
<ul>
    {% for blog in blogs %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ blog.id }}">
            {{ blog.title }}
        </a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

this is models：

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class BlogArticle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='blog_post',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

There is my text1 data：[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51GOi.png)

Comment: Is the link being formatted properly? You can use Inspect Element to see if the `href` is what you expect. Do you get any errors from Django when you click the link?

Comment: Django did not complain, my url is configured correctly, I do not know why the click did not respond

Comment: What address does your link point to? You can right click on it and choose "Inspect Element" to see the actual HTML being rendered.

Comment: Click on the link and then copy the link shown in the address bar of your browser. What does it show?

Comment: What is your main/project url.py?

Comment: no change  Nayan

Comment: Your link is currently just the id of the article with no path. Change your href to a url tag. `{% url 'blog_article' blog.id %}`. I am guessing the urls.py file you pasted is your base project urls. If not, you have to add namespace in the {% url %}

Comment: Also, `(?P<article_id>\d)` has to be `(?P<article_id>\d+)` to capture multiple digits of id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your HTML code to

```
<a href="{% url 'blog_article' blog.id %}">
    {{ blog.title }}
</a>
```

Change your url to

`url(r'(?P<article_id>\[0-9]+)/$',views.blog_article,name='blog_article'),`

Comment: Thanks for your answer